# Как взаимоувязать файлы на сервере и в pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Есть проект на сервере. Задача заключается в импорте проекта на локальную машину. На сервере версии python 2.7.13 и 3.5.3. Используя pyenv устанавливаю версию python 3.8.2. Активируя виртуальное окружение, получаю версию python 3.8.2.Путь до интерпретатора указываю до нужного файла в виртуальном окружении. Но pycharm не видит его, и показывает версию python-а 2.7.13. С чем это может связано и как это исправить?

Comment: В Pycharm нужно в настройках проекта выбрать (изменить) интерпретатор на нужный - из виртуального окружения. Либо создать из самого Pycharm виртуальное окружения, тогда уж точно он будет его "видеть".

Comment: Все делаю как Вы написали. Наверное надо упомянуть, что устанавливаю python используя pyenv.И указываю путь до интерпретатора находящегося в виртуальном окружении соответствующего проекта.